# debugging a program with segmentation fault

Tags: c, debugging

[This challenge from hackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array-in-c/problem?isFullScreen=true) that I was working on successfully compiles with the test run and gives out correct answers with all sorts of input. But when I submit and the code is run with enormous amount of digits [like so,](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/55655/input00.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1633255226&Signature=6Ae46rjT7paEwAbRSbe4miKYWpU%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) I get a segmentation fault.

My best guess is that I am making some sort of mistake while allocating memory to the dynamic 2D array.

Since all my test runs have successfully compiled and given out a correct result I have no idea why it would not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * This stores the total number of books in each shelf.
 */
int* total_number_of_books;

/*
 * This stores the total number of pages in each book of each shelf.
 * The rows represent the shelves and the columns represent the books.
 */
int** total_number_of_pages;

int main()
{
    int total_number_of_shelves;
    scanf("%d", &total_number_of_shelves);

    int total_number_of_queries;
    scanf("%d", &total_number_of_queries);

       //_______________________________________________________________________// 
      //       All malloc() declarations writen by me are here :               //
     //     My guess is, one of this statement is causing the bug.            //
    //_______________________________________________________________________//

         total_number_of_books=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(total_number_of_shelves*1100));
      
         total_number_of_pages=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*total_number_of_shelves);
       
         for (int tnos=0; tnos<total_number_of_shelves; tnos++) 
         {     
              total_number_of_pages[tnos]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*1100);
         }
    

   
    while (total_number_of_queries--) {
        int type_of_query;
        scanf("%d", &type_of_query);
        
        if (type_of_query == 1) {


            //___My code starts here.___//

            int x, y, index;
            scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);

            index=0;
            
            while( total_number_of_pages[x][index]!=0 ) 
            {
                index++;
            }

            total_number_of_pages[x][index] = y;
            total_number_of_books[x]++;    

 //_______________________________________________________________//     
//All code below is a template which was provided by the website.//

        } else if (type_of_query == 2) {
            int x, y;
            scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
            printf("%d\n", *(*(total_number_of_pages + x) + y));
        } else {
            int x;
            scanf("%d", &x);
            printf("%d\n", *(total_number_of_books + x));
        }
    }

    if (total_number_of_books) {
        free(total_number_of_books);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < total_number_of_shelves; i++) {
        if (*(total_number_of_pages + i)) {
            free(*(total_number_of_pages + i));
        }
    }
    
    if (total_number_of_pages) {
        free(total_number_of_pages);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a hint:  the database has three indexes: number of shelves, number of books on shelf, number of pages in book

Comment: @user3629249 I thought of the same but when you think about it, the books are the pages. The best I can represent the books in the array is by their index. As in, b1, b2, b3 because the array doesn't hold any crucial piece of information. So it's better to just place the no. of pages which also represent existence of a book at that index. 2 birds with one stone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `realloc()` to grow the dynamic arrays when you need to put a new element in them. In your code you're doing just one allocation at the start.

For instance, write this at the start (after you `scanf()` to get `total_number_of_shelves` and `total_number_of_queries`):

```c
total_number_of_books = malloc(total_number_of_shelves * sizeof(int));
total_number_of_pages = malloc(total_number_of_shelves * sizeof(int*));

// TODO: you should initialize every element of the first array to `0`,
//   and every element of the second array to `NULL`
```

And when you need to put a new element inside, you use `realloc()`:

```c
total_number_of_books[x] += 1;

total_number_of_pages[x] = realloc(total_number_of_pages[x], total_number_of_books[x] * sizeof(int));

...
```

Comment: To initialise the elements to 0 I replaced malloc() with calloc() and it actually worked (8/10 test cases passed). (1) Which I am really baffled to see because it doesn't make any sense that changing garbage values to '0' suddenly makes the program work. All the values were being changed with page numbers anyway so it shouldn't matter what's the value of the element. (2) Secondly, Is it necessary to use realloc()? I am not growing the dynamic array after taking the no of shelves from the user. The array stays the same size afterwards. I am only populating the array with meaningful values.

Comment: @dumpieceofshit (1) You are using the values before setting them, so they cannot be garbage (for instance, you use `total_number_of_pages[x][index]!=0` in your original code); (2) You use `realloc()` because you do not know what the size of the array will be, until you get input from user. While you could allocate the maximum possible size, it is a bad practice, because in a real-world program, the maximum size could be 16GiB (so.. better allocating the right amount you need).

Comment: For (1)  I see what you mean and it indeed makes sense. But I still get the correct output even with garbage values. Is it sheer luck or maybe it is only true for small test cases? And as for (2) will it be fine if I knew exactly how many entries there would be? Say if the first input consisted of the exact no. of books per shelf? Will using malloc() be alright in that case or should I still use realloc() is such a place?

Comment: @dumpieceofshit (1) Garbage means unpredictable value (so yes, it may also be the value you want, e.g.: `0`), but it's only a matter of luck; (2) if you know the exact number of elements (and that number is not so big, e.g.: 500 elements), you don't need `realloc()` and you can `malloc()` the maximum amount right at the beginning.